# How do I make this JavaScript only work for users on browsers with a min-width of 1036px?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I want to make the `columnWidth` 240 only when the site is viewed on a browser with a min-width of 1036px. So, generally only for desktop users. For any browser width below 1036px, I want the `columnWidth` to be 320. Is this possible?

```
if(jQuery().isotope) {

    $container = jQuery('.home #masonry');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: 240
            },
            getSortData: {

                order: function($elem) {
                    return parseInt($elem.attr('data-order'));
                }

            },
            sortBy: 'order'
        }, function() {

            // Isotope Chrome Fix   
            setTimeout(function () {        
                jQuery('.home #masonry').isotope('reLayout');   
            }, 1000);

        });


    }); 

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $container = jQuery('#masonry');

    jQuery('#filter li').click(function(){

        jQuery('#filter li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');

        var selector = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('data-filter');

        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

        return false;

    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two things, how to find out the screen size and how to make it work for your code.

For screen size you can use the `screen` object (global scope), so `screen.width` is the width of the screen. Or you can use `outerWidth` or `innerWidth` which should return `window` related sizes (they have their quirks though).

Now, regarding your problem, owwyess is suggesting you mix javascript and json notation which isn't possible, so you should do something like

```
 masonry: {
     columnWidth: screen.width >= 1036 ? 240 : 320
 }
```

(If you don't know the syntax, it's called ternary operator, just through it into google)

Comment: Hey David, I tried what you suggested and it looks like the columns now have a width of 240 when the browser width is greater than 1036 which is what I want. However, when I resize the browser's width to less than 1036, the column width remains at 240 instead of going to 320. You can see what I mean with the blogs on the page here: http://keebs.com/sandbox. Basically, when the browser width is greater than 1036, there should be three columns of blogs; and when the browser width is less than 1036, there should be two columns of blogs.

Comment: In that case you will have to listen to the `resize` event on the window and reinitialize your masonry plugin with the changed columnWidth (maybe through `option` and then calling `reLayout`)

Comment: How do I "listen to the resize event"? I'm not sure even where to begin as I am still a beginner.

Comment: Through some searching, I managed to get it to a point where the columns are correct for each browser width. However, I need to refresh the browser in order to "fix" the layout and have the columns reposition. Would you be able to help me get the columns to reposition on their own without the need to refresh? The code I have now is: `columnWidth: $(document).width() > 1035 ? 240 : 320` Any help at all is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Uhm I don't think you can check for the screensize?(not sure), but the browser size is done like this, (if it suits your needs as well):

`if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    // foo
} else {
    // bar
}`

you can also try and change `$(window).width()` to these if it helps:

`$(document).width()`

`$('body').width()`

Your code:

```
if(jQuery().isotope) {

    $container = jQuery('.home #masonry');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.item',
            masonry: {
               $(window).resize(function() {
                if (screen.width >= 1036) {
                columnWidth: 240
                } else {
                columnWidth: 320
                }
               });
            },
            getSortData: {

                order: function($elem) {
                    return parseInt($elem.attr('data-order'));
                }

            },
            sortBy: 'order'
        }, function() {

            // Isotope Chrome Fix   
            setTimeout(function () {        
                jQuery('.home #masonry').isotope('reLayout');   
            }, 1000);

        });


    }); 

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $container = jQuery('#masonry');

    jQuery('#filter li').click(function(){

        jQuery('#filter li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');

        var selector = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('data-filter');

        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

        return false;

    });


}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry that is what I meant. The browser size. Where would I need to wrap that? Around `$container.isotope({ // });` ?

Comment: @Desi you'd wrap it around whatever code you only want to run when the size criterion is met.

Comment: @Desi I have added what I believe you would need, not quite sure though, take a look at it

Comment: I believe window.innerWidth/innerHeight is the screen resolution. Am i mistaken?

Comment: @owwyess I put in your code but for some reason, the columns stay at 320 no matter if the browser is greater or lesser than 1036px. You can see what I mean here: http://keebs.com/sandbox.

Comment: @Desi I have made some changes to the code, try again please

Comment: @owwyess Thanks, but the columns still remain at 320 no matter the width of the browser.

Comment: @Desi hmm, have you tried the different versions I have added in my comment? with `document` and `body`?

Comment: @owwyess Yes, I have and the columns still remain at 320.

Comment: @Desi lol damn. Uhm okay I have editted the code once again to using `if (screen.width >= 1036) {` instead. Maybe that'll work?

Comment: @owwyess I just tried `screen.width` and it didn't work either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49910/discussion-between-owwyess-and-desi)